# Can't insert in a table having composite primary key using LINQ

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, ado.net, composite-primary-key

Added that `SqlConnection` part as someone suggests on this website but still getting exception

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column when identity insert is OFF

on `dv.SubmitChanges();`

The composite primary key is composed of `stid` and `bookid`.

Also please tell me how I can make this query without concatenating textbox's value i.e `bname.Text`

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (DataClasses1DataContext dv = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var iq = (from b in dv.Books
                  where SqlMethods.Like(b.name, "%" + bname.Text + "%")
                  select b.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        IssueInfo info = new IssueInfo()
                             {
                                 stid = Convert.ToInt32(rollno.Text),
                                 due_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text),
                                 bookid = Convert.ToInt32(iq)
                             };

        dv.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT IssueInfo ON");
        dv.IssueInfos.InsertOnSubmit(info);
        dv.SubmitChanges();
        dv.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT IssueInfo OFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139163/identity-insert-and-linq-to-sql)?

Comment: Thanks! But i was thinking why shoudn't i handle the insertion of duplicate rows from code?